# how to set repo for shiny deployment, not working

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, repo, r-inla

I'm running into a deployment issue for my Shiny app.. I'm using a non-CRAN package called R-INLA. It can be installed from here:

```
install.packages("INLA",repos=c(getOption("repos"),INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing"), dep=TRUE)
```

The error message I get from the deploy tab is:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 855023332 failed: Error building image: Error fetching INLA (21.01.13) source. unable to satisfy package: INLA (21.01.13)
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
Package 'INLA 21.01.13' was installed from sources; Packrat will assume this package is available from a CRAN-like repository during future restores
Execution halted
```

Online and through colleagues I've been advised to add the INLA repo to my .Rprofile, so that when it deploys, it downloads straight from there:

```
local({
r <- c(INLA = "https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing",
CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")
options(repos = r)
})
```

Unfortunately, it hasn't worked! Any help/guidance would be extremely helpful.

Let me know if you need any more info.. I'm on a mac running R 4.03, and on RStudio 1.4.1103 preview version.
_
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin17.0
system         x86_64, darwin17.0
status
major          4
minor          0.3
year           2020
month          10
day            10
svn rev        79318
language       R
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out

Thanks!

Jonathan

Comment: When you're taken to the deploy screen (after you hit the publish button), try unchecking the .RProfile box before you click "publish" to deploy

Comment: Thanks @latlio I just tried it out, unfortunately I get the same error message when it's building the INLA package. The deployment doesn't fetch it from the R-INLA.org repository.

`Error building image: Error fetching INLA (21.01.13) source. <CRANPackageSource repo='http://cran.rstudio.org'> unable to satisfy package: INLA (21.01.13)
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :`

Comment: @jdsimkin04 I'm running into the same problem - how did you end up solving this one?